# How to convert plain text to encrypt in flutter (I'am try this but i got some error)

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, public-key-encryption

i'am try to plain text convert to Encrypt formet but i getting this error = Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =

**This is my code**

```
void encrypt(BuildContext context) async {
print("Hiiiis==> ${enteredMobileOtp.value}");
final publicPem = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test/public.pem');
print("Hiiiis==> ${publicPem}");
final publicKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPublicKey>(publicPem);
print("HII==> ${enteredMobileOtp.value}");
final plainText = enteredMobileOtp.value;
final encrypter = Encrypter(RSA(publicKey: publicKey));
final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText);
print("Hii=====> ${encrypted.base64}");}
```

**And getting this error:**

```
E/flutter (15990): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
E/flutter (15990): MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAstWB95C5pHLXiYW59qyO
E/flutter (15990): 4Xb+59KYVm9Hywbo77qETZVAyc6VIsxU+UWhd/k/YtjZibCznB+HaXWX9TVTFs9N
E/flutter (15990): wgv7LRGq5uLczpZQDrU7dnGkl/urRA8p0Jv/f8T0MZdFWQgks91uFffeBmJOb58u
E/flutter (15990): 68ZRxSYGMPe4hb9XXKDVsgoSJaRNYviH7RgAI2QhTCwLEiMqIaUX3p1SAc178ZlN
E/flutter (15990): 8qHXSSGXvhDR1GKM+y2DIyJqlzfik7lD14mDY/I4lcbftib8cv7llkybtjX1Aayf
E/flutter (15990): Zp4XpmIXKWv8nRM488/jOAF81Bi13paKgpjQUUuwq9tb5Qd/DChytYgBTBTJFe7i
E/flutter (15990): rDFCmTIcqPr8+IMB7tXA3YXPp3z605Z6cGoYxezUm2Nz2o6oUmarDUntDhq/PnkN
E/flutter (15990): ergmSeSvS8gD9DHBuJkJWZweG3xOPXiKQAUBr92mdFhJGm6fitO5jsBxgpmulxpG
E/flutter (15990): 0oKDy9lAOLWSqK92JMcbMNHn4wRikdI9HSiXrrI7fLhJYTbyU3I4v5ESdEsayHXu
E/flutter (15990): iwO/1C8y56egzKSw44GAtEpbAkTNEEfK5H5R0QnVBIXOvfeF4tzGvmkfOO6nNXU3
E/flutter (15990): o/WAdOyV3xSQ9dqLY5MEL4sJCGY1iJBIAQ452s8v0ynJG5Yq+8hNhsCVnklCzAls
E/flutter (15990): IzQpnSVDUVEzv17grVAw078CAwEAAQ==
E/flutter (15990): -----END PUBLIC KEY-----' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter (15990): #0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
E/flutter (15990): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15990): #1      parseKeyFromFile
package:encrypt/encrypt_io.dart:8
E/flutter (15990): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15990): #2      GenerateDocumentsOtpController.encrypt
package:curepay/…/controller/geenerate_documeents_controller.dart:55
E/flutter (15990): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15990):
```

Comment: add 'assets/test/public.pem' file to puspec.yaml file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61728460/2828341